# NHibernate LinqProvider / IQueryable: Is FirstOrDefault() supported inside a Where clause?

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

Given two classes that resemble

```
public class Blog
{
    public virtual int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public virtual int CommentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I have a hard time using the following statement:

```
session.Query<Blog>.Where(b => b.Comments.FirstOrDefault().Title.Contains("my title")));
```

The error thrown is:

> Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException

Using .Any() works:

```
session.Query<Blog>.Where(b => b.Comments.Any(c => c.Title.Contains("my title")));
```

However, this is not what I want. In reality, this isn't about Blogs and Comments, but about versioned entities. In the mapping of their parent entity, I order their collection by their version number. I need to be able to access the first entry in order to get the latest version.

Comment: It is not supported because methods like `FirstOrDefault()`, `ToList()`, they finish the IQueryable to a concrete type (primitives types, unique entity and lists). If you call something like this you will get an exception because you are still within the context of an execution, what keeps you from running a sub-query. In this case, you have to use `.Any` method because it will generate a sub-select inside on the SQL statment.

Comment: To solve your problem, you could add a method inside your repository to get the first Comment with a idBlog.

Comment: @Felipe Orani: This is part of a complex query and firing a select for every Blog will not perform very well. A hack would be adding a FirstCommentId property to the entity Blog and map that property through a formula ("Select Top 1 CommentId from ...") and then do a .Any(c=> c.CommentId == b.FirstCommentId && c.Title.Contains("my title")

Answer (score 0):

why not prefilter in db and use linq to objects to finally filter it?

```
var results = session.Query<Blog>()
    .Where(b => b.Comments.Any(c => c.Title.Contains("my title")))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(b => b.Comments[0].Title.Contains("my title")))
    .ToList();
```

or if the Listposition is in the Comments (which is not pretty)

```
Map(x => x.Position, "listindexcolumn").ReadOnly();

var results = session.Query<Blog>()
    .Where(b => b.Comments.Any(c => c.Position == 0 && c.Title.Contains("my title")))
    .ToList();
```

or using a query only property

```
Map(x => this.Position, "listindexcolumn").ReadOnly().Access.None();

var results = session.CreateCriteria<Blog>()
    .CreateCriteria("Comments")
        .Add(Restriction.Eq("Position", 0) && Restriction.Like("Title", "my title"))
    .ToList<Blog>();
```